# Why qiskit.execute runs much slower for inputs with multiple circuits, and how to speed it up?

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am using the "execute" in qiskit to run experiments for two circuits, and it turns out that "execute" runs much slower if the two circuits are run simultaneously, compared to if the circuits are run one at a time. Please see the codes below. Any idea why this happens and how to improve it?

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute
import numpy as np
import time

pi = np.pi

num_qubits = 2
theta = np.random.rand(1,2)[0]

qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
qc.u1( theta[0] , 0 )
qc.cx( 0,1 )
qc.u3( -pi/2 , -pi/2 , pi/2 , 0 )
qc.u2( 0 , pi , 1 )    
qc.cx( 0,1 )
qc.u1( theta[1] , 1 )

qcz = qc.copy()
qcz.measure_all()

qcx = qc.copy()
qcx.h(qcx.qubits)
qcx.measure_all()

# Using execute for the two circuits together
start_time = time.time()
results = execute([qcx,qcz], Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots = 8192 ).result()
print( results.get_counts() )
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

# Using execute for one circuit at a time
start_time = time.time()
resultx = execute(qcx, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots = 8192 ).result()
resultz = execute(qcz, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots = 8192 ).result()
print( resultx.get_counts() )
print( resultz.get_counts() )
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

and the outputs are

```
[{'00': 4114, '01': 4063, '10': 9, '11': 6}, {'00': 2027, '01': 2055, '10': 2074, '11': 2036}]
--- 11.244265079498291 seconds ---
{'00': 4099, '01': 4084, '10': 5, '11': 4}
{'00': 2047, '01': 2034, '10': 2073, '11': 2038}
--- 0.29702305793762207 seconds ---
```

Comment: On which OS are you running it?

Comment: @luciano, I am running on Mac 10.15.1

Comment: Maybe related to this issue?  https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/5373